# To get length of all columns from a table which are greater than 10

Tags: sql, oracle11g

length of all columns which are greater then 10, for suppose if we have 20 columns in table 1 and 2 with 50 rows, in 50 rows for only 10 rows 5 columns are having length greater then 10 , i want that 10 rows list with that 5 columns

select * from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id

Comment: length of what?  edit the question and show all table definitions, sample data, and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1
where length(col1) > 10 or length(col2) > 10 ...etc.
```

You have not provided a complete example as requested, so this is all I can think of for now.